# CGFloat or CGFloat *?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uifont

I am getting an error that I don't understand how to fix. The error is:

```
Sending 'CGFloat' (aka 'float') to parameter of incompatible type 'CGFloat *' (aka 'float *');
```

For line:

```
[xlabel.text drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(labelRect.origin.x, labelRect.origin.y) 
                forWidth:labelRect.size.width 
                withFont:myFont 
             minFontSize:5.0 
          actualFontSize:myFont.pointSize 
           lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap 
      baselineAdjustment:UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignCenters];
```

the error points to `actualFontSize:myFont.pointSize`. `myFont` is a `UIFont`. I set it like so: `UIFont *myFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0];`

What does that error mean and any ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/drawAtPoint:forWidth:withFont:minFontSize:actualFontSize:lineBreakMode:baselineAdjustment:):

> actualFontSize On input, a pointer to a floating-point value. On
>   return, this value contains the actual font size that was used to
>   render the string.

Which means that you have to pass in a pointer, by referencing a variable. To do so you use the ampersand operator `&`

Example:

```
CGFloat outSize = 0;
[xlabel.text drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(labelRect.origin.x, labelRect.origin.y) 
                forWidth:labelRect.size.width 
                withFont:myFont 
             minFontSize:5.0 
          actualFontSize:&outSize 
           lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap 
      baselineAdjustment:UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignCenters];
NSLog(@"%f", outSize);
```

drawAtPoint: will set the value that outSize points to and so you can print the result.
The reason for this here is, that you can only return 1 value in C via return statement. To get multiple results, you can pass in pointers to allow the method to set additional results.

Answer (score 3):

The `actualFontSize` parameter is supposed to be the address of a CGFloat that you pass in. If the method uses a different font size, it'll change the value that you pass in, which is why you need to pass the address instead of the value. In other words, you're passing `actualFontSize` by reference so that the method can update it as necessary.